# Artifactory : Application could not be initialized: Invalid DNS name: maven.domain.org:-1

Tags: artifactory

I'm trying to upgrade Artifactory from 6.18 to 7.3.2 and I'm facing error like Invalid DNS name maven.domain.org:-1 . This is not the real dns name I have but the DNS name reported already exist and was running for version 6.18.

```
2020-10-22T19:05:51.377Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [cdd01d4e0b52e2fc] [actorySchedulerFactoryBean:727] [art-init            ] - Starting Quartz Scheduler now
2020-10-22T19:05:51.470Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [cdd01d4e0b52e2fc] [ifactoryApplicationContext:271] [art-init            ] - Artifactory context starting up 58 Spring Beans...
2020-10-22T19:05:51.959Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [cdd01d4e0b52e2fc] [OnboardingYamlBootstrapper:100] [art-init            ] - can't import file artifactory.config.import.yml - Artifactory repositories have already been created
2020-10-22T19:05:51.977Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [cdd01d4e0b52e2fc] [o.a.s.a.AccessServiceImpl:408 ] [art-init            ] - Initialized new service id: jfrt@01bpj5k40d37v91t153m5y15sa
2020-10-22T19:05:52.035Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [cdd01d4e0b52e2fc] [oryAccessClientConfigStore:590] [art-init            ] - Using Access Server URL: https://maven.domain.org/access source: System Property
2020-10-22T19:05:52.826Z [jfac ] [INFO ] [5c8eee656ba614dc] [s.r.NodeRegistryServiceImpl:63] [http-nio-8081-exec-3] - Cluster join: Successfully joined jfrt@01bpj5k40d37v91t153m5y15sa with node id artifactory.server
2020-10-22T19:05:52.869Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [cdd01d4e0b52e2fc] [.a.c.AccessClientBootstrap:169] [art-init            ] - Cluster join: Successfully joined the cluster
2020-10-22T19:05:52.871Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [cdd01d4e0b52e2fc] [o.j.a.c.g.AccessGrpcClient:74 ] [art-init            ] - Connecting to grpc server on maven.domain.org:-1
2020-10-22T19:05:52.884Z [jfrt ] [INFO ] [                ] [o.j.c.w.ConfigWrapperImpl:504 ] [Thread-17           ] - [Node ID: artifactory.server]  detected local  modify for config 'artifactory.security.access/access.admin.token'
2020-10-22T19:05:53.121Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [cdd01d4e0b52e2fc] [ctoryContextConfigListener:115] [art-init            ] - Application could not be initialized: Invalid DNS name: maven.domain.org:-1
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.configure(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:249)
        at org.artifactory.webapp.servlet.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener$1.run(ArtifactoryContextConfigListener.java:111)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException: Failed to initialize bean 'org.artifactory.security.access.AccessService'.; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid DNS name: maven.domain.org:-1
        at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.refresh(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:281)
        at org.artifactory.spring.ArtifactoryApplicationContext.<init>(ArtifactoryApplicationContext.java:159)
        ... 6 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid DNS name: maven.domain.org:-1
        at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:217)
```

It makes a week I'm searching why the configuration don't grab the port instead of -1 in dns name.

Thank you for your help.

Patrice